# Update jQuery UI Slide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want the code below to function as it already does but I want to also be able to run the slide function (slide: `function(e,ui) {`) onclick of another div when `unitStandard` and `unitMetric` are changed. Is there a way to call this function?

```
$('#weight').slider({ 
    max: 450,
    min: 50,
    value: 115,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(e,ui) {
        if(unitStandard == true) {
            weight = Math.floor(ui.value); 
            $('#weightVal').html(weight + " lbs");
        }
        else if(unitMetric == true) {
            weight = Math.floor(ui.value); 
            weight = weight*0.453592;
            weight = Math.floor(weight);
            $('#weightVal').html(weight + " kg");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by calling the `value(v)` method as documented in the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value).

For example:

```
$("#some-div").on("click", function() { $("#weight").slider("value", 200); });
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/9UpHS/15/).

If you don't give it a second argument `$("#weight").slider("value")`, it will return the current value of the slide.